# Node.js Express Request XML only returning header

Tags: xml, node.js, express, response

Using http://expressjs.com/ and https://github.com/request/request to make an API call and return an XML response to browser. However it's returning the Header instead of the body.

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var app = express();

app.get('/search', function(req, res, next) {
    var url = 'http://someApi';

    res.send(request(url, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            return body;
        }
    }));
});
```

This is what gets returned

```
{
    "uri": {
        "protocol": "http:",
        "slashes": true,
        "auth": null,
        "host": "",
        "port": 80,
        "hostname": "",
        "hash": null,
        "search": "",
        "query": "",
        "pathname": "",
        "path": "",
        "href": ""
    },
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "host": "api.someapi.com"
    }
}
```

Comment: Question need some more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Express does not naively parse XML. You would need to use a package like
[express-xml-bodyparser](https://github.com/macedigital/express-xml-bodyparser). Here is an [article](https://farcasmihai91.github.io/jekyll-portfolio/blog/parsing-xml-in-node-express) I wrote in regards to this. 
I hope will help you with this question.

Comment: From the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.